# Why isn't there a Spring MediaType like MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_UTF8?

Tags: java, spring

Why doesn't this exist?

```
MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_UTF8
```

There is a json MediaType with the utf-8 charset i.e.

```
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8
```

but the xml version doesn't exist. Does anybody know why Spring didn't include it? 
For reference I'm talking about (org.springframework.http.MediaType)

Answer (score 0):

Because its not required for xml. Utf8 charset for json exists, because there is (or was, who knows) a bug with some of the browsers.

[You can refer this commit for more info](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/27e87e559362026b132c42856c7d7bf7ff65f9ee)

[Also this if you're even more interested](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13600)

Comment: It may not be a requirement of xml but when you interface different APIs for a living you'd be surprised how many need the encoding expressly specified.